# Custom Activity Confusion

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I have followed the tutorial here:

https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node

I have successfully deployed to app to a heroku dyno. However, when I try to load the custom activity, it is not available in the UI.

I have queried the network tab and got this:

[image]

It returns a 404 for the config.js. Is the same as the config.json file? I am sure I have deployed them onto the server

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue. Journey Builder looks for a js file instead of a json file now.

So create a config.js file with the contents of

```
define([], function(){      
    return {
        "icon": "images/icon.png",
        "iconSmall": "images/iconSmall.png", 
        "key": "EXTENSION_KEY",
.....

};
});
```

This fixed it for me.